# I want to convert a whole column into the date format of yyyymmdd, I do not want the current date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, date

I want to convert a whole column into the date format of `yyyymmdd`, I do not want the current date, thus I cannot use `getdate()` command, there is already data in the column, I just need the right command to convert the whole column into `yyyymmdd` format.

The column I am using is `FIELD_034` and the table is `Sur_CompassAuto1_1_7_fetch`.

I am using SQL Server.

Thank you

Comment: What type is the field defined as?

Comment: Check my edits, that should work for both `DateTime` and `Varchar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common misconception is that a `datetime` has a format. If you are storing your dates as a datetime, then you can output it in any format.

It sounds as though you might be storing your values as a `Varchar`.  You would be better off converting your varchar dates into a datetime, then you can do whatever you want with them

That said, if you HAVE `FIELD_034` as a `DateTime`, then its as easy as

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), FIELD_034, 112)
from Sur_CompassAuto1_1_7_fetch
```

If the field is a varchar its similar:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, FIELD_034, 112)
from Sur_CompassAuto1_1_7_fetch
```

The difficulty of this one is if you have your values in different or nonstandard formats.  Then it would require some clean up to make the query work.

Edit: as @AArnold says, its 112 instead of 111.  [Date formats are subtle.](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I fully agree with the paqogomez's response, but instead of date style of 111, better use 112. 
The output for the statement

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), FIELD_034, 111)
```

will result in **yyyy/MM/dd**. Where as,

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), FIELD_034, 112)
```

will return **yyyyMMdd**, which is what he needed.

Comment: Its the simple things that get you.  Excellent catch. +1. I'll edit my answer.